# Qwerty Azerty in custom keyboard ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

Is it possible to Add Qwerty and Azerty in custom keyboard for iOS
I have a file DefaultKeyboard.swift and i tried  to add anything like AzertyKeyboard.swift

Thank you on avance

Answer (score 1):

Apple requests that each keyboard language is added in a `UIInputViewController` of its own. De-facto, all the keyboards are changing languages inside the same `UIInputViewController` by replacing the layout or keyboard map.

You can choose either way.